# Can't install Laravel using Homestead with Vagrant + Buildbox

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I have installed Vagrant, VirtualBox and Homestead correctly, made all configurations correctly, when I try to run composer command to install Laravel on my VM using SSH I got this error :

```
[ErrorException]
mkdir(): Protocol error
```

**And here is a screenshot of the error :**
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I don't what is causing that

Comment: Is there any this guys?